# Creating an object from from an ID (or name)

Tags: c#, .net

I have an abstract class that a lot of child classes inherit:

```
  public abstract class CrawlerBase
    {
        public abstract void Process(string url);
    }
```

I'm working on this loop:

```
foreach (var item in result)
                {
                    object crawler = null;

                    switch (item.Type)
                    {
                        case "Trials":
                            var t = new Trials(); 
                            ct.Process(item.URL); //repetitive code.  
                            break;

                        case "Coverage":
                            var c = new Coverage();
                            c.Process(item.URL); //repetitive code.
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }

                   // crawler.Process(item.URL);
                }
```

Now the item.type string will depend on what child class needs to be instantiated. Since all my child classes inherit my base class, it would be very repetitive to call .Process() in every case statement.  I want to cast the object "crawler" to the child class being instantiated, and call the crawler.Process() at the end of the switch statement, as shown in the comments.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many way to create a type from a string. Reflection can be one of them, it's **slow** (but if you're processing web requests probably you won't care of this) but you won't need to keep a long list of hard-coded strings and/or to have an ugly long switch/case statement.

If speed is not a problem then let's start with something easy:

```
CrawlerBase crawler = (CrawlerBase)Activator.CreateInstance(
    Type.GetType("MyNamespace." + item.Type));

crawler.Process(item.URL);
```

Using reflection you do not need switch/case and, it doesn't matter how many types you have, you won't change your factory code to accomodate new implementations of `CrawlerBase`. Simply add a new implementation et-voila.

How it works? Well you can create an instance of a class from its `Type` definition (using [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx)) so the *problem* is to get the `Type`. `Type` class provides a static [`GetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) method that can be used to create a `Type` from its (full) name. In this case we supply a namespace, it must be changed to the real one, if you keep all your classes in the same namespace you may write something like this:

```
string rootNamespace = typeof(CrawlerBase).Namespace;
```

And then the maked-up version:

```
CrawlerBase crawler = (CrawlerBase)Activator.CreateInstance(
    Type.GetType(rootNamespace + "." + item.Type));

crawler.Process(item.URL);
```

### Improvements 1

This is a very naive implementation, a better version should cache `Type` in a dictionary:

```
private static Dictionary<string, Type> _knownTypes =
    new Dictionary<string, Type>();

private static GetType(string name)
{
    string fullName = typeof(CrawlerBase).Namespace
        + "." + name;

    if (_knownTypes.ContainsKey(fullName))
        return _knownTypes[fullName];

    Type type = Type.GetType(fullName);
    _knownTypes.Add(fullName, type);

    return type;
}
```

Now you're OK, you do not need to manage a (possibly) long list of strings, you do not need to change an endless switch/case if you add/remove/change a type and to add a new Crawler all you have to do is to derive a new class. Please note that this function isn't thread-safe so, if you'll have multiple threads, you have to add a lock to protect dictionary access (or a `ReadWriterLockSlim`, it depends on your usage pattern).

### Improvements 2

What's next? If your're requirements are more strict (about security, for example) you may need to add something more (I think it's not your case so you may not even need the type dictionary). What to do more? First you may check that the created type derives from `CrawlerBase` (using `IsAssignableFrom` and to provide a more meaningful exception instead of `InvalidCastException`), second you may decorate your classes with an attribute. Only classes with that attributes will be created (so you can keep *private* implementations that even if marked as public cannot be created from your users). There is much more than this but a simple implementation usually is enough to solve this kind of problems (when the input doesn't come from user but from robust configuration file or from the program itself).

Comment: This is fantastic.  You just saved me heaps of time!

Comment: @broke you welcome! I use this quite often. Before .NET 4 (with System.Xaml) usually from XML to implement a kind of custom XAML.

Answer (score 4):

Does this not work?

```
foreach (var item in result)
{
    CrawlerBase crawler = null;

    switch (item.Type)
    {
        case "Trials":
            crawler = new Trials(); 
            break;
        case "Coverage":
            crawler = new Coverage();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if(crawler != null)
        crawler.Process(item.URL);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make dictionary with factory methods:

```
var factories = new Dictionary<string, Func<CrawlerBase>>
{
  {"Trials", () => new Trials()},
  {"Coverage", () => new Coverage()},
// and so on
}
```

...and throw away `switch`:

```
foreach (var item in result)
{
  factories[item.Type]().Process(item.URL);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't do this?

```
 {
   CrawlerBase crawler = null;

   switch (item.Type)
   {
        case "Trials":
            crawler = new Trials();   
            break;

        case "Coverage":
            crawler = new Coverage();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
   crawler.Process(item.URL);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

As Redi pointed out you do call call Process on any instance since all derive from the same base class. You still have some repetitive code in your switch case which can be simplified if you move away from a switch (if/else) to a mapping construct.

```
Dictionary<string, Type> Types = new Dictionary<string, Type>
{
    { "Trial", typeof(Trials) },
    { "Coverage", typeof(Coverage) },
};

void Crawl()
{
    string itemType = "Trial";
    CrawlerBase crawler = (CrawlerBase)Activator.CreateInstance(Types[itemType]);
    crawler.Process("url");
}
```

You can do it also with delegates like Dennis if you put a factory method as value into your dictionary.