# Cast by FullTypeName

Tags: c#, casting

I have to cast an object to an object, where i just have the `typename` as a string.

For example:

I have the type-string `System.DateTime` and the string `2012-09-17T10:19:23.5369243+02:00`. Now I want to have an object of `DateTime` with the value of the string.

Is this possible?

Comment: Generally, this is not possible as the string representation of a class often doesn't contain all data to reconstruct the object from it. Think about a nested object graph for example. Having said that, it is quite possible for certain types.

Comment: It's possible but it's not a cast. See [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ey1cdcx8(v=vs.100).aspx). Unfortunately there is not any GENERAL way to achieve this for all types (probably because conversion to/from string implies a lot of non trivial details, like locales and custom representations).

Comment: String to DateTime: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165448.aspx ,  in a general sense this may be hard to do for all kind of objects.

Comment: You should consider using the JSON serialiser. Then you can go in both directs relatively easily.

Comment: What do you want to do with the result? You can't actually treat it as `DateTime`, because that would require that you know the type at compile time.

Comment: Well i wanted to serialize objects and then recreate it. But now i have another way to do this. I use the binaryformatter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question can be found in all the other answers, waiting to be pieced together. :)

1. Get the Type from your Type String, like akhisp said:

   ```
   Type dateTimeType = Type.GetType("System.DateTime");
   ```
2. Now, use a type converter to change the string to the DateTime:

   ```
   object date = Convert.ChangeType("2012-09-17T10:19:23.5369243+02:00", dateTimeType);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Usually this kind of conversion is not exposed through a cast. There are many reasons for this (and it could be a nice topic for an another question).

Sometimes the string representation of an object is pretty "standard" for that object. For example a color may always be serialized as a comma separated RGB triplet.

Things become harder when the type you need to parse introduces locale-dependent representations: a date, for example. In this case framework designers decided to do not introduce an interface like `IParseable` and to do this kind of stuff using a 3rd object:`TypeConverter`s, `TypeDescriptor`s and conversion classes. It makes your code more complicated but it allows to manage very complex conversions delegating the work to another class, take a look to:

- [System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.aspx) on MSDN.
- [System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on MSDN.
- [Understanding the TypeDescriptor: A Metadata Engine for Designtime Code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/parthopdas/archive/2006/01/03/509103.aspx)

For primitive types you may not even need to use them: you can rely on `IConvertible` interface and [System.Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class.

You can't do it with a cast (thanks God, in my opinion) but you can write a generic `Parse` method that accepts a `string` and returns the type you need, something like:

```
T Parse<T>(string value)
```

For what I remember there is a nice open source type conversion library ([Universal Type Converter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/248440/Universal-Type-Converter)). It manages a lot of conversions using everything it may find to convert a type to another (imagine, for example, how many different string representations you may use for a `bool` value). Even if you won't use it directly you should read the article to understand how this things works (and to take a look to source code to see how corner cases have been handled).

Comment: I think the question is about something more: the *type* is also a string, not just the object.

Comment: @svick you're right, it's trivial but he may take a look to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938067/creating-an-object-from-from-an-id-or-name/10938166#10938166).

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is use the Type.GetType(String) method to get the Type of the object.
Then I would do a call to Activator.CreateInstance(Type Object[]) to construct an instance of that object, assuming you know that there is a constructor that takes in a string.

Comment: But even DateTime does not have such constructor. Moreover, even if present and even if we may assume it's what we need we still have the problem of the format of the string...