# how can i turn a string into an class reference in c#?

Tags: c#, string, class, reference

in c# i am working on an text based adventure where each tile is represented by a class. in my main class i have inserted a way of reading from the console and in a class that i have called tile loader i have an update function. this function gets a string from the input read at the start. when i call it i want the string to be converted into an class reference so that i can call the class and an load function witch is inside of each tile class. i could just go ahead and insert a lot of if's but i don't really want to do that. i know there is an easier way.

Comment: Easiest way is...a dictionary (key = string, value = type of your class). You may also consider reflection (by name or by attributes). First solution is easier to implement but harder to maintain, second is easier to extend but (IMO, little bit) more error prone (because of localization, for example)

Comment: For an example (using Reflection) take a look to [this anwer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938067/creating-an-object-from-from-an-id-or-name/10938166#10938166) I posted some time ago here on SO for a similar question. Code is pretty raw so just consider it a starting point.

Comment: Sorry. i am new to c#. i was just wondering if you could show me a short example of how i would do this.

Comment: You welcome! Just follow that link, there is some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do this.

You will need to provide an assembly name or reference and may need to add the namespace for the class unless you want to provide the fully qualified class in the command line.

For example, assuming that the class `Test` is in an assembly called `WindowsFormsApplication1` and the user entry is in a variable called `sInputClassName`, the following code will create an instance of the class in the `oClass` variable:

```
        // What the user entered
        var sInputClassName = "Test";

        // The name of the assembly; there are other ways to get this, such as through reflection
        const string CLASS_ASSEMBLY_NAME = "WindowsFormsApplication1";
        // Get the requested type from the entered class name and assembly name
        var oType = Type.GetType(CLASS_ASSEMBLY_NAME + "." + sInputClassName, true);
        if (oType != null) {
            // Once we have the class type, create an instance of it
            var oClass = Activator.CreateInstance(oType, false);
            if (oClass != null) {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Created " + sInputClassName);
            } else {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Could not create " + sInputClassName);
            }
        } else {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Could not find " + sInputClassName);
        }
```

Comment: Incidentally, I recommend always passing `true` as the second argument to `Type.GetType`, causing it to throw a nicely descriptive exception if for some reason the type cannot be loaded. I speak from experience when I say that debugging type load errors in production code is *very very* annoying when all you get back is null -- annoying because I could have saved a lot of time if only some developer had typed six extra characters.

Comment: @MichaelLiu: Good catch and very helpful info. I have updated the answer to reflect this.